# How to make an executable(.exe) that packages a nodejs server? (not UI-centric)

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, executable

I have implemented a nodejs server that serves incoming requests to use the bluetooth services of the local computer. I want the nodejs server to be packed as an windows executable file so that I can distribute it. People should be able to just install/run that .exe which will install any packages required (if any) and run the server. How to do this?. I saw and tried node-webkit etc., but they are UI-centric, that is it can pack a nodejs application that opens a html page. But I want my server javascript file to be executed, like the way it is done in command prompt : `node file-name.js`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've a server running with nodejs and for execute this I use a .bat file.

- Create a .bat file
- Inside of the file put: 
  cd path/to/server/
  node índex.js

Comment: This means that the source files will be present there and we just execute bat script right? But I want everything to be packed into a single file :/

Answer (score 0):

I used [JXCore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) for this task in the past. It basically creates one executable that includes everything. 
Unfortunately active development of is halted.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

You can use [nexe](https://jaredallard.me/nexe/) for that.

> Create a single executable out of your node.js app

[image]

## Motivation

- Ability to run multiple applications with different node.js runtimes.
- Distributable binaries without needing node / npm.
- Starts faster.
- Lockdown specific application versions, and easily rollback.
- Faster deployments.

Comment: I'll look into nexe